# vba Excel: Parameters in a sub. What is the change?

Tags: vba, excel, function

I have a sub at Excel like this:

```
Sub epign()
et = 4529
ep = 1
fc = 3
ent = 9992
Dim resultado As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
Ruta = "C:\TRABAJO\MisEstados\"
libro = Ruta + CStr(et) + "\" + CStr(et) + "-data.xlsx"
Nombre = "'" + libro + "'!D_" + CStr(ep)
soloLibro = CStr(et) + "-data.xlsx"
ws = "D" + CStr(ep)
resultado = 0
Set myRange = Workbooks(soloLibro).Worksheets(ws).Range("D_" + CStr(ep))
resultado = Application.VLookup(ent, myRange, fc, False)
End Sub
```

This works great and the result is a positive number.

But, I have tried to use this sub from a function like this:

```
Function epig(et As Integer, ep As Integer, fc As Integer, ent As String) As Variant
Call epign(et, ep, fc, ent)
epig = resultado
End Function

Sub epign(et As Integer, ep As Integer, fc As Integer, ent As String)
Dim resultado As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
Ruta = "C:\TRABAJO\MisEstados\"
libro = Ruta + CStr(et) + "\" + CStr(et) + "-data.xlsx"
Nombre = "'" + libro + "'!D_" + CStr(ep)
soloLibro = CStr(et) + "-data.xlsx"
ws = "D" + CStr(ep)
resultado = 0
Set myRange = Workbooks(soloLibro).Worksheets(ws).Range("D_" + CStr(ep))
resultado = Application.VLookup(ent, myRange, fc, False)
End Sub
```

When trying to use this on an Excel cell:

```
=epig(4529;1;3;"9992")
```

The result is an error 2042.

Why? What is the difference?

Comment: Call epign(et, ep, fc, ent) remove the brackets for starters

Comment: `1` Dim resultado As Variant should be declared on top and not in Sub epign( `2` Debug and check what is the value that you are getting for "resultado = Application.VLookup(ent, myRange, fc, False)" `3` Check if there is something which is breaking the code

Comment: You need to move `Dim resultado As Variant` so the variable is declared above both procedures, or just make `epign` a function.

Comment: Declaring resultado as public would solve it but there are so many issues at play here. The concept of calling a sub from a function means there can be unexpected behaviour, not to mention you may as well have the logic for calculating the value within the function itself. Finally input aspects such as the filepath really ought to be parameters as they're likely to change.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The value for resultado is still Error 2042, even when declaring resultado in Function

Comment: Also ALWAYS use Option Explicit at the top of every code module

Comment: From the documentation: "_The #N/A error generally indicates that a formula can’t find what it’s been asked to look for._" So the VLookup fails.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I obviously know what is the #N/A error in a VLookup formula. The question is why it does works in a Sub and does not in a function

Comment: Note: in the sub `ent = 9992` in the Function it is `ent = "9992"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the result of a function you assign the result to the name of the function. To use a function in your spreadsheet it must be Public and in a normal module (not those attached to workbook or worksheets)  All you need is:

```
 Public Function epig(et As Integer, ep As Integer, fc As Integer, ent As String) As Variant
 Dim resultado As Variant
 Dim myRange As Range
 Ruta = "C:\TRABAJO\MisEstados\"
 libro = Ruta + CStr(et) + "\" + CStr(et) + "-data.xlsx"
 Nombre = "'" + libro + "'!D_" + CStr(ep)
 soloLibro = CStr(et) + "-data.xlsx"
 ws = "D" + CStr(ep)
 resultado = 0
 Set myRange = Workbooks(soloLibro).Worksheets(ws).Range("D_" + CStr(ep))
 resultado = Application.VLookup(ent, myRange, fc, False)
 epig = resultado  'add this line

 End Sub
```

You can then enter =epif(4529, 1, 3,9992) into a cell and get a result

Comment: After the line  `resultado = Application.VLookup(ent, myRange, fc, False)` the function ends (it even doesn't go to `epig=resultado`

Comment: It looks like the vlookup isn't returning a result.  Should ent be a string or a long?

Answer (score 0):

`epig = resultado` is probably the eror: `resultado` is not a variable of the function and Sub `epign` doesn't return it. You need a way to communicate the result to the function, which then can return it to the sheet.

In Tools, Options, turn *Require Variable Declaration* on. That will warn you about these errors.

Now, how to comunicate the result. I suggest you use a global variable `resultado`, e.g.:

```
Public resultado As <type>    ' (I cannot see what type it is)
```

Or make it a parameter of the Sub, e.g.:

```
Sub epign(et As Integer, ep As Integer, fc As Integer, ent As String, ByRef resultado As <type>)
```

Comment: In that case it should have a defalut value of `0` :)